# When img and div set to same width why does div get smaller?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="conatainer">
    <div class="block">
        <img class="img" src="img.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
img {
width: 480px;
}

.block {
    border: solid 2px;
    width: 480px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

the div takes size 472 px. Why is that and how to fix it.
The image overlaps the div.

Comment: can you share your entire code.?

Comment: for sure you have box-sizing:border-box set so 480 - 2*2 - 2*2 = 472

Comment: ok got it didn't know padding and border was part of width I thought width was just internal width.